# How do I figure out the length of polyline features in a feature class with a WGS 1984 coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, coordinate-system, wgs84

I'm trying to figure out lengths of polyline features in a feature class with a WGS 1984 coordinate system.

Here's code to list lengths:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> inFc = r"C:\Users\e1b8\Desktop\E1B8\GIS_Stackexchange\data.gdb\test"
>>> sr = arcpy.Describe (inFc).spatialReference
>>> sr.name
u'GCS_WGS_1984'
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (inFc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for geom, in cursor:
        print geom.length

0.000785568606752
0.000784558202405
0.00117166138222
0.000816779544786
```

I'm not sure what units these lengths are in. I know it's generally in the coordinate system's linear units, but WGS 1984 has no linear units.

```
>>> sr.linearUnitName
u''
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able to write code that works with distances and is compatible with both projected and geographic coordinate systems. Usually I use the spatial reference's `metersPerUnit` property to get to a common unit regardless of the coordinate system's unit, but this throws an error for WGS 1984:

```
>>> sr.metersPerUnit

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    sr.metersPerUnit
AttributeError: SpatialReference: Get attribute metersPerUnit does not exist
```

So again, how can I get the length of features? And preferably, how do I figure out their lengths in meters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought at first the [arcpy.Polyline.getLength()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000008000000) method would work, as you can specify a measurement type and units but it did not because it is GCS. As you can see here, we are still in Decimal Degrees:

```
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line_wgs", 'SHAPE@') as rows:
...     for row in rows:
...         print row[0].getLength('PLANAR', 'METERS')
...         
0.00193201661559
>>> desc = arcpy.Describe("line_wgs")
>>> desc.spatialReference.factoryCode
4326
```

What you can do is add a spatial reference to your search cursor (such as the Web Mercator):

```
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line_wgs", 'SHAPE@', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(102100)) as rows:
...     for row in rows:
...         print row[0].getLength('PLANAR', 'METERS')
...         
215.071313581
>>>
```

Note, since WGS Web Mercator is in meters you can just use the length property as you did in your first one:

```
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line_wgs", 'SHAPE@', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(102100)) as rows:
...     for row in rows:
...         print row[0].length
...         
215.071313581
>>>
```

Comment: Careful! Web Mercator is not actually in meters and should not be used to calculate length/distance/etc. I would suggest using a UTM Zone projection that intersects your data.

Comment: I can't access Arc right now to verify, but think arcpy.Polyline.getLength() will still work if you specify the _measurement_type_ as "GEODESIC" rather than "PLANAR" for a GCS. But passing the spatialref as an argument in the cursor to quickly re-project on-the-fly is great too!

Comment: @ John you're right about `getLength()` working when measurement_type is set as "GEODESIC". In my case, it returns the value in meters. Do you happen to know if this is always the case for geographic coordinate systems?

Comment: @Mintx that is a good point.  You could use any projection in there, I just used web Mercator as an example I thought everyone would be familiar with.

Comment: From my knowledge Emil, "GEODESIC" always bases measurements from the underlying _geographic_ coord. system, even if you have a projected coord. system on top of that. There are some cases where you have a projected coord. system, but the underlying geographic coord. system is "undefined". Not sure if it will still return length in METERS reliably in these special cases. I know @dmahr wrote [an article](http://www.dmahr.com/2015/07/geodesic-areas-arcmap-field-calculator/) about coord system measurements that might be useful.

Comment: I've never heard of a situation where a valid Esri coordinate system reference could have an "undefined" GCS.  It's either a valid GCS, or a PCS based on a valid GCS.  You could define some bizarre "marble-sized Earth" for your GCS, but even that would not be "undefined".

Comment: @Vince I may be thinking the situation where the user defines a PCS in the Data Frame in ArcMap, but the actual data itself has an undefined coord. system. Or someone passes a coordinate system in the spatialref argument of their cursor to project on-the-fly but the underlying coord. system for the data is still undefined. Or someone uses the "Project" tool when they really meant "Define Projection". Weird combos like that that might make getLength() unreliable.

Comment: Again, those conditions can't be met.  The data frame CS would supersede the data CS, or the cursor CS would,..  You can have an error state with an invalid coordsys, but not a valid coordsys with an invalid GCS -- the projection engine just won't bend that way.  There are plenty of ways to foul up coordinate *data* so that innocent coordrefs get blamed when distance is unreliable, but that's a different story.